# What is involved in PHP's startup sequence?

Tags: php, apache

Regarding `display_startup_errors` the PHP manual says that even when `display_errors` is on, errors that occur during PHP's startup sequence are not displayed. So then what is meant by PHP's startup sequence? What does it involve, and what kind of errors can occur there? Some common examples could help.

Comment: well, php.ini misconfigured for example. the file that is supposed to be executed not readable. that kind of stuff that happens, before any php file is actually parsed.

Comment: Thanks Jakumi, that's a good example. I have also read http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php. But, for example, where does the PHP 'startup sequence' start. How can we tell that it has ended and that the parsing of the php files has started? What does the start up have to do with things like .htaccess in several folders, modules and extensions, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The most common types of errors you'll see that would be suppressed by `display_startup_errors` are going to be related to PHP failing to load modules or modules emitting error messages for various reasons.

For example:

> PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/path/to/module.so' - /path/to/module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

This means PHP is configured to load `module.so` but it's not found so it cannot be loaded.

A module might also emit a warning due to bad ini configuration values:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: session.name cannot be a numeric or empty '' in Unknown on line 0

This is one of several warnings the session extension emits, in this case because the configuration value for `session.name` is numeric or empty.

Most of PHP's startup sequence is going to revolve around configuring itself, loading in dynamic modules, calling each module's GINIT and `PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION` so they can initialize, then running PHP's startup sequence.

How and when these things happen vary depending on what server API PHP is running under.  For Apache, this might be as an Apache module, FPM, CGI/FastCGI.

Some good references that talk about this are:

- https://www.slideshare.net/laruence/the-php-life-cycle
- http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/php7/extensions_design/php_lifecycle.html
- https://wiki.php.net/internals/extensions#extensions_lifetime

Comment: ...so enabling/disabling `display_startup_errors` would never affect **coding errors**, correct?